# Haskell, Length of list returning the value 1

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm working with some code and there seems to be an issue which I can't figure out.

So I've got a method which decrements an input Int by 1 until it hits 5. (I know if i enter less than 1 it would cause an error but i will fix that later)

I have a second function which calls a takes a List as a parameter which calls this function and returns the list of numbers, I want to call length on this list and populate a separate list (I'm not the best at explaining, i'll show with code examples below)

```
sub 5 = return [1]
sub x =
    do 
        xs <- sub (x - 1)
        return (x:xs)       


f xs = [ length (sub x) | x<-xs ]
```

If I call sub 10 on it's own it gives the output [10,9,8,7,6,1], however if I call length on this, it gives the output [1].

In my head i thought the output would be 6, as it has 6 elements in.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and/or a way to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the type of `sub`?  Try `:type sub` when you have this code loaded in GHCi.

Comment: sub :: (Num t, Monad m, Eq t) => t -> m [t], I did have it with the types above the functions but somebody said that over complicated things and to just try without, thanks for your reply

Comment: The type of `length` is `[a] -> Int`.  As it turns out the list type `[]` is an instance of `Monad`, so when you call `length (sub x)`, the type of `sub` gets specialized to `t -> [[t]]`, where `m` is replaced by `[]`.

Comment: Oh i see, is there anyway to convert in haskell? I know other programming languages have toString or similar functions.

Comment: Are you wanting to convert `[[t]]` into `[t]`?  There is the `concat` function which does this.  BTW, "converting values from one type to another" is precisely what functions are, and if you haven't noticed by now Haskell is really good at functions ;)

Comment: haha yes, i've noticed. however, if length is [a] -> Int how come I can call  length [10,20,30]. Do the Int value get converted into characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sub doesn't return `[10,9,8,6,1]` but `[[10,9,8,6,1]]` (a list of list) therefore the length is 1. You don't need the return. You are in a list monad, `return` wraps it's value into a list, this why you end up with nested list. Your code should be

```
sub 5 = [1] -- or return 1
sub x = do
       let xs = sub (x -1)
       (x:xs)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so you're saying my list is within a list at the moment? Also i tried to work with that code and it gave an error:
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t ~ [t]

Comment: my mistake you need to replace the `xs <-` by `let xs`. The code is then equivalent to `sub x = x:sub (x-1)` as pointed by Jedai

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that this sub function is written like you were in an imperative language and that return doesn't mean the same thing in Haskell : it means "wrap this thing in a Monad (which Monad depends on the context)". Here since you use length on the result of sub the list [] monad is used and the result is [ [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5] ] a list of one element which happen to be a list of 6 elements. mb14 correctly identified that but then corrected only the first case of your function, the second case is also monadic but shouldn't be...

```
sub 5 = [1]
sub x = x : sub (x - 1)
```

is the simple code you should be using, you don't need any monad here...